# Error when building yii2 starter kit webpack part : EAI_AGAIN, XSym: not found , 0025: not found , webpack.js: not found

Tags: npm, webpack, yii2, yarnpkg

Error when building yii2 starter kit  webpack  part , with the process that used to work always in the past following the docs, the error was following as follows:

**1st run**

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.15.1)

No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.15.1)

No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.
> docker-compose run -T --rm webpacker npm i npm@latest -g
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-08T16_53_57_669Z-debug.log
Script docker-compose run -T --rm webpacker npm i npm@latest -g handling the docker:build event returned with error code 1
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**2nd run**

```
> docker-compose run -T --rm webpacker npm run build

> @ build /app
> webpack --progress

/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 1: XSym: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 2: 0025: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 3: 04ec15c01fc3c268b6405aedcd29653e: not found
/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack: line 4: ../webpack/bin/webpack.js: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ build: `webpack --progress`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-08T16_59_54_662Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to issue the yarn command and I ended up with the following alert output:

```
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.22.4", while you're on "1.12.1".
info To upgrade, download the latest installer at "https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi".
Done in 43.21s.
```

So I upgraded my yarn, and it somehow started to work immediately.